# Fixing old cocos2d project on iOS 7

Tags: xcode, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I've created an iPhone game which utilizes some code from an old version of the Cocos2D iPhone game development framework and I've got a wee bit of a problem running it on iOS 7.

The version of Cocos2d from which the code was used was probably 0.98.

The actual class is called QuadParticleSystem (in newer versions it's been deprecated by CCParticleSystemQuad).

The actual issue is that the game runs fine on iOS 6 and below. It even runs fine on iOS 7 if the deployment target is set to iOS 6.0 and SDK version set to 7 (at least when put on the device directly using XCode).

The problem is that when the game is uploaded to the appstore, Apple seems to strip out the whole iOS 6 compatibility thing and the particle emitters fail to show up among other things like alpha transitions, invisibility etc.

(They initialize correctly and everything, but they simply DO NOT render).

I've considered (and tried somewhat) upgrading the Cocos2D version, but due to the old third-party frameworks I've used for other things there is a hell of a lot of linking/dependency/deprecation errors which could take forever to fix (if it's at all possible, which I doubt) In other words, I've wasted too much time on the project already and am looking for a quick fix.

If no one knows any solutions could anyone at least direct me to docs where I can see how to create/insert a new particle emitter system in the existing code?

I've thought about using SpriteKit's native emitter system, but I don't know how to incorporate it within the current code (as I've never had dealings with SpriteKit) and am not sure if it's even possible.

I've also thought of maybe upgrading the GL ES framework within that old version of Cocos2D just in case Apple have killed off some functionality of older versions of OpenGL. Then again that could take a while.

Comment: You can't mix cocos2d with other OpenGL views like Sprite Kit. Your best bet is probably to bite the bullet and upgrade to at least cocos2d v2.x

Comment: I would say 'at most' 2.x' ... the forklift update from 2.x to 3.x is quite intense :)